Domain controller not loading certificate for LDAPS
I have Active Directory and can connect using LDAP on port 389.
I enabled LDAPS , but it fails when using ldp.exe with the error:
Cannot open connection
In event viewer I see:
LDAP over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) will be unavailable 
at this time because the server was unable to obtain a certificate.

Additional Data
Error value: 8009030e No credentials are available in the security package

I generated the certificate using Let's Encrypt.
The certificate is in the local computer Personal store. The isrg root x1 is in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store.
The r10 and r11 in the Intermediate Certification aAuthorities store.
A Certificate registry value was added to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LDAP  with the certificate thumbprint.
openssl s_client result:
write to 0x25be4ad1e10 [0x25be4b003c0] (322 bytes => -1)
write:errno=10054
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Protocol: TLSv1.3
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read from 0x25be4ad1e10 [0x25be4a77de0] (16384 bytes => -1)

What else am I missing?

Does your certificate meet the requirements? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/requirements-domain-controller
